# Using Thread to make positive numbers in assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I'm having trouble getting Mathematica to use my assumptions.  Here's a simple example:

```
FullSimplify[Sign[(a)],Assumptions->Thread[{a,b,c}>0] && Element[{a,b,c }, Reals]]
```

This just gives me "Sign [A]".  I think I'm doing the "Thread" wrong, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: The assumption `a > 0` already assumes that `a` is real, so you don't need the second assumption. That said, if you *did* need it, do `Append[Thread[{a, b, c} > 0], Element[{a, b, c}, Reals]]` instead. The problem is that `Thread[{a, b, c} > 0]` makes a list, which you are joining to `Element[{a,b,c }, Reals]` with `And`, which requires a sequence of logical expressions, not a list of logical expressions.

Comment: Or use `Thread[And[a, b, c] > 0, And]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @march using the assumption `a > 0` automatically makes `a` an element of reals.

Below is the output of `Thread`

```
Thread[{a, b, c} > 0]
(* {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0} *)
```

It is a list and works fine as long as we don't try to use it with an `And` or an `Or`.

```
FullSimplify[Sign[(a)], Assumptions -> Thread[{a, b, c} > 0]]

(* 1 *)
```

Assuming that one wanted to merge it with other `And` or `Or` expressions, replace the head of the list with `And` by using `Apply`.

```
FullSimplify[Sign[(a)], Assumptions -> And @@ Thread[{a, b} > 0] && c > 0]

(* 1 *)
```